# Modify Ant Design (antd) time picker footer text

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is there any way to modify the text from the "Now" and "Ok" button in Ant Design Time Picker? Either using react or antd.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe renderExtraFooter with the text you want and set showNow=false? Play with the various options https://ant.design/components/time-picker/#API

Comment: There is also a prop panelRender on the Common API https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#Common-API

Comment: the problem is that I do like the functionality of these buttons, but I just want to change the text to something else more intuitive. I appreciate the replies.

Comment: I dug into the docs more and found the actual answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the text of the "Now" and "Ok" buttons by using the `locale` prop.  You must provide a complete locale configuration, not just the `lang.now` and `lang.ok` properties.  So you can import one of the standard language configs and merge them.

```
import { TimePicker } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import locale from "antd/es/date-picker/locale/de_DE";

console.log(locale);

export default () => (
  <TimePicker
    locale={{
      ...locale,
      lang: {
        ...locale.lang,
        now: "Current Time",
        ok: "Submit",
      }
    }}
  />
);
```

You can also set sitewide labels using a [ConfigProvider](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#Localization).

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at props if something is available to modify the footer, the only prop I found relevant to footer was 'renderExtraFooter', seems like there is nothing from ant that we can use to replace the text of these buttons.

However, there is a CSS way to replace the text using *::after* selector like below.

```
a.ant-picker-now-btn {
  font-size: 0;
}

a.ant-picker-now-btn:after {
  content: "ABC";
  font-size: 16px; /* original font size */
}
```

Sharing the codesandbox below -
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4150-forked-pyd95?file=/index.css

Comment: `font-size: 14px;` will look better.

Comment: thats actually a smart way to do it - im gonna try this - cheers mate!

Comment: @CosminMocanu -- Cool, accept the answer if it helps

Comment: i checked the other answer even tho this works, it is more of a "hack" lets say. But i do appreciate your answer and if I could i would have checked both as valid, since i've tested both. This is also easier so props to you for providing such a good solution. Stay safe

Comment: I agree @CosminMocanu, answer which came later is a more sophisticated ant way of achieving this.